# Linear Programming with $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, matlab

When solving a linear programming problem in MATLAB using `linprog` of the form

$$ \min c^T x $$

subject to

$$ Ax \leq b, \; \left\| x \right\|_{1} = 1 $$

if we need to enforce the additional constraint that $L_1$ norm of $x$ is $1$, or $\|x\|_1=1$, how can this be converted into a set of inequations of the above form so that the trivial solution $x=0$ can be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this problem cannot be formulated as an LP, since the constraint $\| x \|_{1}=1$ describes a non-convex set and the feasible set of linear programming problem is always a convex set.

Comment: Would you agree with the answer below?

Comment: @Linalg's answer below gives you a couple of work arounds.  Neither amounts to formulating the original problem as an LP.  Sumit's answer is incorrect, since the author of the question isn't trying to minimize $\ x \|_{1}$.

Comment: Could you tell me how this constraint is a non-convex set? Conventionally all norms are convex sets.

Comment: $x=(1,0,0)$ has $\| x \|_{1}=1$.  $y=(-1,0,0)$ has $\| y \|_{1}=1$.  $(1/2)x+(1/2)y=(0,0,0)$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $y$ which has norm 0.  Thus the set of vectors with norm 1 isn't a convex set.  Note that the set of vectors with $\| x \|_{1} \leq 1$ is a convex set.

Comment: @Sumit: you are confusing convex _functions_ and convex _sets_. Norms are indeed convex _functions_. But the set described by $\|x\|_1 = 1$ is not a convex _set_.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGrant for clarifying.

Comment: This argument is not enough if one is allowed to augment the number of variables. It's not being said that the feasible set of both problems need exactly be the same, for example.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian notes, the problem is not convex. There are two workarounds for this.

1. It seems like the right hand side of $||x||_1=1$ is arbitrary. Maybe you can replace it with $x_1=1$ (if you know that $x_1\geq  0$)? Or solve two problems: one with $x_1=1$ and one with $x_1=-1$? This only works if you know $x_1 \neq 0$.
2. You can use binary variables to deal with the nonconvexity:
   $$ \sum y_i = 1$$
   $$ y_i = x_i + s_i$$
   $$ y_i = -x_i + t_i$$
   $$ 0 \leq s_i \leq M b_i$$
   $$ 0 \leq t_i \leq M (1-b_i)$$
   $$ y_i \geq 0$$
   $$ b_i \in \{0,1\}$$
   The big-M constraints set either $s_i=0$ or $t_i=0$. Consequently, $y_i = x_i$ or $y_i = -x_i$. Since $y_i\geq 0$, we obtain $y_i = |x_i|$.

Answer (score -1):

We have

$\|x\|_1= |x_1| + |x_2| + ... + |x_n|$

which is equivalent to

$ \max\{x_1,-x_1\}+\max\{x_2,-x_2\}+...+\max\{x_n,-x_n\}$

So $\|x\|_1=1$ can be substituted as

$y_i \geq x_i$

$y_i \geq -x_i$

$y_i \geq 0$

Then the minimum $L_1$ norm solution for $x$ is given by $y$.

Comment: Your solution is only valid when $y$ is minimized. If you add a constraint $\sum y_i=1$, you do not exclude $x=0$, since $y_1=1$, $ y_i=0$ ($i\geq2$) is a feasible solution.